# Freichat chat's not showing his/her name who logged in?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I've made my small own social networking site. Recently I added a [freichat](http://codologic.com/page/) chat script. Now I'm confused when user log in into my site I cannot see his/her name, it's shwoing his/her named as "Guest102" blah blah ..

I did't understand this. Please help I want to show their name not guest blah... Please help.

My *loggedin.php* code :

```
<!-- if you need user information, just put them into the $_SESSION variable and output them here -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--===========================FreiChat=======START=========================-->
    <!--    For uninstalling ME , first remove/comment all FreiChat related code i.e below code
         Then remove FreiChat tables frei_session & frei_chat if necessary
             The best/recommended way is using the module for installation                         -->

    <?php
    $ses=null;

    if(!function_exists("freichatx_get_hash")){
        function freichatx_get_hash($ses){

            if(is_file("C:/Users/Raj/PhpstormProjects/socialnetworking1/chat system/hardcode.php")){

                require "C:/Users/Raj/PhpstormProjects/socialnetworking1/chat system/hardcode.php";

                $temp_id =  $ses . $uid;

                return md5($temp_id);

            }
            else
            {
                echo "<script>alert('module freichatx says: hardcode.php file not
found!');</script>";
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascipt" src="http://localhost:63342/socialnetworking1/chat system/client/main.php?id=<?php echo $ses;?>&xhash=<?php echo freichatx_get_hash($ses); ?>"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:63342/socialnetworking1/chat system/client/jquery/freichat_themes/freichatcss.php" type="text/css">
    <!--===========================FreiChatX=======END=========================-->
    <title>Maiit kota-rajasthan</title>
</head>
<style>
    body{
        background-color: #D0D0D0;
    }

    #menu_header{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0%;
        left: 0%;
        right: 0%;
        height: 5%;
        background-color: black;
    }

    #right_box{
        position: fixed;
        width: 20%;
        right: 0%;
        top: 6%;
        height: 93%;
        background-color: white;
        font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 30px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33);
        -moz-box-shadow:    0px 1px 30px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33);
        box-shadow:         0px 1px 30px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.33);
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

</style>
<body>
<div id="menu_header">

</div>
<div id="right_box">
<p style="text-align: center;">Today's Top faces</p><hr>
    <a href="index.php?logout">Logout</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Hey, <?php echo $_SESSION['name'] ?>. You are logged in.
Try to close this browser tab and open it again. Still logged in! ;)

<!-- because people were asking: "index.php?logout" is just my simplified form of "index.php?logout=true" -->
<a href="index.php?logout">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Freichat generates the guest name by using random function in its php script.

1. Receive user name and password from user and store user name in session, 
   $_SESSION["name"]=$userid;
2. Open freichat.php which is in Server directory, and add this code.

$custom_gst_name = $_SESSION['name']; //user name from session,comment previous assignment

The Login ID entered by user will be displayed instead of guest.

Answer (score 0):

Go to freichat/hadcore.php
Edit the following to suit your database and also table and table column,
/* Custom driver */

$usertable='user'; //specifies the name of the table in which your user information is stored.

$row_username='name'; //specifies the name of the field in which the user's name/display name is stored.

$row_userid='id'; //specifies the name of the field in which the user's id is stored (usually id or userid)

Remember to use custom config when installing it